# Is my WriteConsole solution correct?

Tags: c, windows, console

Here is the book question:

> Modify the `CatFile` function in the program so that it uses
>   `WriteConsole` rather than `WriteFile` when the standard output handle
>   is associated with a console.

And here is my solution:

```
static VOID CatFile(HANDLE hInFile, HANDLE hOutFile)
{
    DWORD nIn, nOut;
    TCHAR buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    LPTSTR pBuffer = &buffer[0];

    while (ReadFile(hInFile, buffer, BUF_SIZE, &nIn, NULL) &&
        (nIn != 0) &&
        (WriteFile(hOutFile, buffer, nIn, &nOut, NULL) || WriteConsole(hOutFile, pBuffer, _tcslen(pBuffer), &nOut, NULL)));
    return;
}
```

The part from the `||` sign in the code above is my addition to the code.

My question is to know if that would work once `WriteFile` wouldn't be `TRUE` since `hOutFile` is a handle of a console?

Another part of the question is just about the `WriteConsole` function: are these the correct arguments?

Answer (score 1):

No comment on what your call as I don't know what WriteFile() or WriteConsole() do.

But that is seriously abusing the `&&` and `!!` operators.
I don't think I would ever let that code pass a review:

```
while (ReadFile(hInFile, buffer, BUF_SIZE, &nIn, NULL) &&
    (nIn != 0) &&
    (WriteFile(hOutFile, buffer, nIn, &nOut, NULL) || WriteConsole(hOutFile, pBuffer, _tcslen(pBuffer), &nOut, NULL)));

// Why not write it like this:

// While we manage to read a good value:
while (ReadFile(hInFile, buffer, BUF_SIZE, &nIn, NULL) && (nIn != 0))
{
     if (!(   (WriteFile(hOutFile, buffer, nIn, &nOut, NULL))
          || (WriteConsole(hOutFile, pBuffer, _tcslen(pBuffer), &nOut, NULL))
          )
        )
     {
          // Write Error
          break;
     }
}
// Now check for read errors to report.
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick thought - Shouldn't WriteFile actually work when hOutFile is the console?

Otherwise I guess that you may need to check whether GetStdHandle(...) == hOutFile.